Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Upgrade - Can't Login - Disk Issue
During the update to 22.04.5 LTS, computer became unresponsive and had blinking dashes across the top. I restarted and got a tty1 login screen and found the cause is NTFS partition damage - I think. Can someone confirm that I need to replace this SSD?
I've also included the analysis from partition 2 in the last screenshot.




You have no network at this point. Go back to the recovery menu, choose "enable networking" and retry the apt --fix-broke install command.

@jos thanks, I thought I'd enabled it and didn't realize it worked. Seems it's failing? I added another picture where I took a photo - the black part at the bottom appears only for a second then goes away.  Not sure I'm connected? Would the menu change or would it still say enable networking?  Do I go to root to run apt --fix-broke install?  I get a response saying command line option --fix-broke install is not understood in combination with the other options

My bad, the proper command is apt --fix-broken install.

Thanks @Jos, I did that before and got the same result.  Can you tell from the second to the last pic if my network is enabled?  apt --fix-broken install not working

If you are unsure whether your network works, just try ping google.com or ping 8.8.8.8.

Needs more pictures.

Try this:
A. Boot your PC with the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.
B. Open a terminal,
Press Ctrl+Alt+T
C. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a hard drive.
sudo fdisk -l

-----October 7, 2024 - Edited-----
Suppose it informs that / is /dev/sda2, and /boot/efi is /dev/sda1, continue running:
 sudo umount /dev/sda2
 sudo umount /dev/sda1
 sudo fsck -y /dev/sda2
 sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
 sudo mkdir /mnt/boot
 sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
 sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   
 sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
 sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
 sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
 sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
 sudo chroot /mnt  /bin/bash 
 grub-install /dev/sda
 nano /etc/resolv.conf

In the open file paste these lines:
 nameserver 208.67.222.222
 nameserver 208.67.220.220

Ctrl+O Save File
Ctrl+X Close nano
Continue running:
 nano /etc/apt/sources.list

In the open file delete content and paste these lines:
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble main restricted universe multiverse

 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse

 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse

 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse

Ctrl+O Save File
Ctrl+X Close nano
Continue running:
 dpkg --configure -a
 apt -f install
 apt -m install
 apt update
 apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 apt dist-upgrade
 apt autoremove
 apt clean
 umount /mnt/dev/pts
 umount /mnt/dev
 umount /mnt/proc
 umount /mnt/sys
 umount /mnt/boot/efi
 umount /mnt
 exit
 sudo reboot

And boot your PC with the hard drive

thank you so much - I added a few photos. Before I realized how many were in the list I started the umount for loop 11-14. Is that going to mess anything up? Should I only do the first step for sda 1 or also sda 2?  I do all of this after pressing 'continue testing', correct?

Your logs imply that you did ''not'' remove any foreign libraries before update. (Ubuntu can't handle that) My guess is that you should install from scratch. I think @kyodake analyzed it correctly.

@kanehekili I followed the steps and I'm still getting the tty1 login. In the process I got one warning (last photo) also all packages not upgraded (second to last photo).  Also, it said the sources file moved, but I proceeded to make changes in the folder instructed. Should I make changes in the updated sources folder (3rd from last screenshot)?

@kyodake thanks but want to confirm that I should make the changes in  nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources because as my screenshot shows that's where the directory moved.  Also, when running  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi  it produces result that mount point does not exist.  Should I enter sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi  ?

Also to be clear, I am running Ubuntu (safe graphics) and then selecting 'Try Ubuntu' correct?

@kyodake sorry not sure how I missed that step.  when running sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi it says the device /dev/sda1 doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS. Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/sda not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Looks like your ntfs partition is damaged.  If it is a physical disk issue, you are going to need another disk, if you want to have a good chance of recovering your data.
Assuming it is not a physical disk error:
Boot into the live system like you have.
Then use apt to install testdisk.
This program is great when you need to recovery partitions that are broken or have been deleted.
run testdisk, select the drive, and do a scan.  With any luck it will find the partition, and you can do a list of the files before you write any chances, and confirm the files are listed and the data is really there.  If it is, then you can just write the partition table to the disk, and hopefully that is it.
If it is a physical disk issue, then I recommend adding another drive, booting into the live system, and using the program "dd" to copy the disk eg:
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/location/of/the/new/disk/image.img conv=noerror,sync 

This will create a raw bit image of your disk, allowing you to then work on recovering the files, without causing more loss of data.
Good Luck

thanks much, added 2 new photos. Just want to confirm that it is a physical disk issue and I can't just delete the partition somehow - understanding there'd be a loss of data (I have important stuff on external HD).

What type of drive is this? I assume it is a 1TB drive  if it is a single disk, not raid/zfs or some other combination of disks, then you may need to go into advance mode and just correct the Values of the C/H/S.  With that said, if you have the important stuff backed up, you can delete the partition, and do a low level format, but personal I would not use the drive again, I would replace it.
